# isdigit() always passes the check

Tags: c++, eclipse, pointers, optimization

Hello i want to check in my program if the user instead of typing a digit if he typed something that is not a digit.

so i did this function

```
void ValidationController::cinError(int *variable){

    if(!isdigit(*variable)){
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        cout <<*variable<<endl;
        *variable=0;
        cout <<*variable<<endl;
    }
}
```

i call the function like this:

```
int more;
cin >>more;
cinError(&more);
```

So my problem is that everytime i give a digit it acts like i didn't.It goes inside if and makes the variable equal to zero.What am i missing here?

Comment: [isdigit](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit) operates on character codes from a `char*` array.  If you already have a single `int` variable, it is automatically a number but its value probably won't be the character code for a single digit.  What do you expect `cinError` to do?  There is no possible input to a function that takes `int` that isn't a number.

Comment: i expect to test if the input from the user is a digit and if this is not true to set the variable that was set from the cin equal to 0 else to leave the variable as it is

Comment: Then you can not read in an integer. A string would be a better choice.

Comment: @simonc `isdigit` does _not_ operate on `char`; it is undefined behavior to call it on a `char` (in most systems).  It operates on an `int` whose value is required to be in the range `[0...UCHAR_MAX]` or `EOF`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Leaving aside the fact that you are using `isdigit` incorrectly, it's too late to check for `isdigit` anyway, because you are reading an `int`. In this situation it is the stream's `>>` operator that looks for digits, not your code.

If you want to validate the user input, read the data into a `string`, and then use `isdigit` on its components, like this:

```
string numString;
getline(cin, numString);
for (int i = 0 ; i != numString.length() ; i++) {
    if (!isdigit((unsigned char)numString[i])) {
        cerr << "You entered a non-digit in a number: " << numString[i] << endl;
    }
}
// Convert your validated string to `int`
```

Comment: But don't forget that calling `isdigit` with a `char` is undefined behavior; you have to cast to `unsigned char` first.  (And frankly, I'd use `std::find_if` rather than your loop.)

Comment: @JamesKanze That's a fair point, thanks for correcting this! I would use `std::find_if` as well, but I think that doing so would confuse the OP too much at this point of his "learning curve".

Comment: well i read isdigit and i thought it will read the char stored in the int and test if the character code is a digit.probably there is something i misunderstood.Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @kyrpav The character isn't stored in an `int`; it's stored in a `char`.  The `char` is implicitly converted to `int`, giving a value in the range `[CHAR_MIN...CHAR_MAX]`.  `isdigit` requires a value in the range `[0...UCHAR_MAX]` (or `EOF`).

Answer (score 2):

Check comments for the your `isdigit` issue

Back to solution, how about exception handling ? (I'll prefer dasblinkenlight's solution though )

```
  cin.exceptions(ios_base::failbit); 
  int more;
  try
  {
    cin >> more;
    if (!isspace(cin.get()))
       /* non-numeric, non-whitespace character found
         at end of input string */
      cout << "Error" << endl;
    else
      cout << "Correct" << endl;
  }
  catch(ios_base::failure& e)  
  {        
  /* non-numeric or non-whitespace character found                    
   at beginning */
    cout << "Error" << endl;
  }
```